# iText output PDF not working in Adobe Acrobat, Android App

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I'm developing an Android App which creates a PDF report using iText. The report text only is fine and opens in all PDF programs. But then I want to put an image in like a logo at the top and Adobe Acrobat says the file is corrupt. I can load the PDF on the android device and images show. I need it working on Acrobat though.  Any ideas?

Here's my code.

```
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos );
        writer.open();
        ChapterCount = 0;
        document.open();
        addMetaData(document);
        addTitlePage(document);

        /* Inserting Image in PDF */
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(cntx.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);
        Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

        //add image to document
        document.add(myImg);

        addContent(document);
        document.close();
        writer.close();
```

Comment: Please share a sample pdf.

Comment: Hi i've figured out the problem. I actually wasn't copying the latest report even though it looked like the latest, something with my old device and MTP not showing all files. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282

Comment: You might want to make that an answer (and accept that answer as soon as you can) or else delete the question. It should not remain an open stack overflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've figured out the problem. I actually wasn't copying the latest report even though it looked like the latest, something with my old device and MTP not showing all files. [code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282)